# Regex expression for matching ranges

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following issue:

- A string is to be validated via regex-expression.
- The string contains ranges or single values separated by a semicolon, e.g. `100-200;10;2300-3400;34;`
- The maximum value of each number is `99999`.
- No letters are allowed in the string.

What I have up to now:

```
^([0-9]{1,5}[-][0-9]{1,5}[;])? ^([0-9]{1,5}[;])? ([0-9]{1,5}[-][0-9]{1,5}[;])?([0-9]{1,5}[;])? ([0-9]{1,5}[-][0-9]{1,5}[;])*$? ([0-9]{1,5}[;])*$?
```

Thus my regex consists of three optional group-types:

- Beginning: `^([0-9]{1,5}[-][0-9]{1,5}[;])? ^([0-9]{1,5}[;])?`
- Middle: `([0-9]{1,5}[-][0-9]{1,5}[;])?([0-9]{1,5}[;])?`
- End: `([0-9]{1,5}[-][0-9]{1,5}[;])*$? ([0-9]{1,5}[;])*$?`

This regex doesn't solve my issue though as for example letters within the input-expression often return true but should return false. Any idea on how to solve this?

This is a simplified version of the regex following the comment by RB:

- Beginning: `^(\d{1,5}\-\d{1,5};)? ^(\d{1,5};)?`
- Middle: `(\d{1,5}\-\d{1,5};)? (\d{1,5};)?`
- End: `(\d{1,5}\-\d{1,5};)*$? (\d{1,5};)*$?`

Comment: how about negative `-10-10` ranges and descending ranges `200-100`?

Comment: Negative ranges are not allowed, descending ones are

Comment: Why not just use string split first split by semicolon and then by dash.  Finally use int.TryParse.

Comment: @jdweng Although I agree with that approach here it appears the OP is only doing validation so that may be overkill, however if they are using the results then I'd do that

Comment: You may use [`\A(?<val>[0-9]{1,5}(?:-[0-9]{1,5})?)(?:;(?<val>[0-9]{1,5}(?:-[0-9]{1,5})?))*;\z`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cA%28%3f%3cval%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c5%7d%28%3f%3a-%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c5%7d%29%3f%29%28%3f%3a%3b%28%3f%3cval%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c5%7d%28%3f%3a-%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c5%7d%29%3f%29%29*%3b%5cz&i=100-200%3b10%3b2300-3400%3b34%3b).  The `val` group captures will hold the values. Well, the regex pattern can be built dynamically to make it more readable.

Comment: @jdweng I have updated my answer to include your suggestion

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I may be missing something but what's the advantage of that long expression compared to the simple one in my answer?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: It is not long. Have you seen email and URL regexes? No advantage, it is a regex to both validate and extract the necessary values from string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have indeed but relatively speaking then...

Comment: @Chris Note that you can upvote and accept answers that help you out that is what those features are there for. Please do not edit this information into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this to extract the groups:

```
\b(?<FirstNum>[1-9][0-9]{1,4})(-(?<SecondNum>[1-9][0-9]{1,4}))?;
```

[Permalink to RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3CFirstNum%3E%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%29%28-%28%3F%3CSecondNum%3E%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%29%29%3F%3B&i=100-200%3B10%3B2300-3400%3B34%3B1234-%3B12345678912345%3B12-45%3B) including two invalid test cases `1234-` and `12345678912345`.

Then to check if it contains any letters just use the below expression:

```
[A-Za-z]
```

and validate it with:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[A-Za-z]");
if (regex.IsMatch(inputString))
{
    //Invalid string
}
```

---

Although a regex is useful for this if you actually need to use the ranges later on it is better to use a combination of `string.Split` and `int.TryParse`:

```
string input = "100-200;10;2300-3400;34;";

string[] ranges = input.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string range in ranges)
{
    string[] numbers = range.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string number in numbers)
    {
        int parsedNumber;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(number, out parsedNumber))
        {
            //Invalid input
            break; //Or return false...
        }

        //Use parsedNumber here
    }
}
```

Comment: The regex will allow input such as `1234-` and `1234512345`. Also it does allow leading (or all) zeroes though the original one did as well, so just pointing that out

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Good catches I have updated so it should work now

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I have added a permalink now for testing now too and fixed another problem so it checks for a word boundary at the start of the match